# progressBar moving irrevently

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiprogressbar

i'm using a progressbar to show upload percentage of a file uploading to ftpserver, for the first time it is updating well,when i cancel the upload and and again id i start that. for 50% of upload progress bar is filling ,for third time for 25% total progress bar is filling.

here is the code (i'm using s7ftp class to upload to server)

```
- (void)uploadBytesWritten:(S7FTPRequest *)request {


if (uploadedData < totalFileSize) {
    uploadedData = uploadedData + request.bytesWritten;
}
float total = (float)totalFileSize;
float bytes = (float)request.bytesWritten;
float pt = (bytes/total);
float totalSizeMb = (total/1048576);
//    NSLog(@"File Size in Mb:%f",totalSizeMb);
float uploadDataMb = (uploadedData/1048576);
NSString* totalSize = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%5.1f", totalSizeMb];
NSString* uploadData = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%5.1f", uploadDataMb];
//    float str = (uploadDataMb/totalSizeMb);
float str = (uploadedData/total);
float string = str*100;
int PercentageFinal = roundf(string);
 NSString *uploadPercentage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",PercentageFinal];
uploadpercentage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Mb/%@Mb", uploadData, totalSize];
NSLog(@"Uploading percentage:%@",uploadpercentage);
NSString *percentage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",pt];
uploadProgressView.progress += [percentage doubleValue];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]   postNotificationName:@"UpdatePercentageNotification" object:nil userInfo:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:percentage, @"percentage",uploadpercentage,@"UploadPercentage",uploadPercentage,@"Percent",nil]];

}
```

in another class

```
-(void)Viewdidload{
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updatePercentageNotificationOne:) name:@"UpdatePercentageNotification" object:nil];
  }

- (void)updatePercentageNotificationOne:(NSNotification *)notification{
NSLog(@"Updating percentage in upload all view");
 //    NSString *uploadpercentage = [[notification userInfo ]objectForKey:@"UploadPercentage"];
//    NSLog(@"Percentage:%@",uploadpercentage);
NSString *percent= [[notification userInfo]objectForKey:@"Percent"];
NSLog(@"percent:%@",percent);
NSString *percentage = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"percentage"];
//    NSLog(@"Percentage......%@",percentage);
percentageLabel.text = percent;
ProgressBar.progress +=[percentage doubleValue];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:@"UpdatePercentageNotification"];

 }
```

Comment: where you did alloc init for progressbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K 
When you start upload again progressBar needs to be reset. You just alloc init it when user clcks on upload.

Comment: Then may be some others values like totalFileSize, uploadedData are not initialesed properly.